# Django TestCase works with Sqlite3 - doesn't work with Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-testing

I'm trying to figure out why my tests are working with `Sqlite3` but don't work with `Postgres`.

import os

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase

from products.factory import ProductFactory
from products.models import Product, Organisation
from products.services.imports import ImportService
from users.factory import UserFactory, OrganisationFactory
from users.models import User


class ProductTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls) -> None:
        cls.org = OrganisationFactory.create(name='My organisation')
        cls.user = User.objects.create_user('peter','xxxxxxxx')
        cls.user.organisation = cls.org
        cls.product = ProductFactory.create(title='Title', created_by=cls.user, organisation=cls.org)


    def test_product_has_organisation(self) -> None:
        self.assertTrue(self.product.organisation, 'Product has no organisation')
```

When running it with `Postgres` it raises:

```
ERROR: test_product_has_organisation (products.tests.test_product.ProductTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milano/PycharmProjects/.virtualenvs/markethelper_api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "products_product" violates foreign key constraint "products_product_updated_by_id_33940c75_fk_users_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (updated_by_id)=(19) is not present in table "users_user".
```

The Product.updated_by:

```
updated_by = CurrentUserField('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='updated_products', null=True, blank=True,
                              verbose_name='Updated by', on_update=True)
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: It is an issue with the package you are using, see: https://github.com/PaesslerAG/django-currentuser/issues/47

Comment: Sqlite3 by default does not enforce [FK's](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys), Postgres does. That is why the difference in behavior. What the test is telling you is that `products_product.updated_by_id` is not present in `users.user`. So you need to make sure the user is present before doing the update.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver Is there a way to set user as "current" so the `updated_by` can be populated?

Comment: Honestly,  I have no idea what `updated_by` is doing and where it is getting its information. I would add information to your question about the `Product`, and `ProductFactory' relationship, as well as how `updated_by` fits in?